# Closest power of 2

Tags: c

Given an unsigned integer `a` (less or equal to `1024`), I need to find a number `p` which satisfy the following condition :

- lowest `p >= a`
- `p` is a power of 2

I'm sure there is a better solution, using bitwise operators.
Have you a better solution ?

```
unsigned int closest_pow2(unsigned int a)
{
  if (a == 0 || a > 1024) return 0; //error, never happen
  if (a == 1) return 1;
  if (a == 2) return 2;
  if (a <= 4) return 4;
  if (a <= 8) return 8;
  if (a <= 16) return 16;
  if (a <= 32) return 32;
  if (a <= 64) return 64;
  if (a <= 128) return 128;
  if (a <= 256) return 256;
  if (a <= 512) return 512;
  if (a <= 1024) return 1024;
}
```

Comment: look at the << operator

Comment: Does this question really relate to an actual problem you had? Then, please, tell us about it!

Comment: Yes, this is the size of the buffer used in my reduction algorithm (part of dot product) on GPGPU considering the number of elements to reduce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following does it without the relatively expensive conditional statements or loops:

```
unsigned next_power_of_two(unsigned int x) {
   x = x - 1; 
   x = x | (x >> 1); 
   x = x | (x >> 2); 
   x = x | (x >> 4); 
   x = x | (x >> 8); 
   return x + 1; 
}
```

Comment: It may be fast, but it's hardly clear or readable (took me half a minute just to find a hand-wavy argument that it's correct), unlike other fast (though admittedly dependent on a fast `clz` intrinsic) implementations. In other words, I would not call it "better".

Comment: It took me even longer than @delnan to come to my conclusion that it works (cut-paste-click run-test with some unsigned ints), no hand waving though.  But given the very well chosen, descriptive name, and that it is all of 6 lines of code, readability is never going to be a hugh issue.  Nifty.  +1.

Comment: This style of code is typical for mathematicians not aware of everyday programming. C programmers would have used operators like `--` and `|=`, and had an eye on the future readers of his code. The solution may be smart and "fast", but without a reference in a doc comment, it results in a huge waste of developer's time: [-1] ps: there's no indication of a *need for speed* in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Stylistically, I prefer not to use bitwise operators because they tend to make the code harder to read--they encapsulate the bit structure much less than other types of commands.  Even without bitwise operators, the code could be made much more concise:

```
int pow = 1;
if (a == 0 || a > 1024) return 0;
while (pow < 2000) {
    if (a <= pow) return pow;
    pow *= 2;
}
```

If you don't want to hardcode a number larger than the largest number of bits (probably a better coding practice anyway), you can write as follows:

```
final int MAX_POSSIBLE_BIT_VALUE = 1024;

unsigned int closest_pow2(unsigned int a) {
  if (a == 0 || a > MAX_POSSIBLE_BIT_VALUE) return 0;
  int pow = 1;
  while (pow <= MAX_POSSIBLE_BIT_VALUE) {
    if (a <= pow) return pow;
    pow *= 2;
  }
  return pow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a trick question (since I see no requirement that you must find the **lowest** p >= a), then this is a solution:

```
return 1024;
```